What is correct way to use dependency of a dependency library in .Net Core 8.x
Background
I'm building an app that depends upon a DLL which in turn has a dependency upon the Sqlite component.
My main app has no direct dependency upon Sqlite.
But, it does call functionality in the dependency which then writes to Sqlite.
It would basically look something like the following:

Main App Calls Data Service
The app makes a call to the Data Service, which in turn saves data in the Sqlite db.
Main App CSPROJ - ref to sub library
The csproj of the main app has a reference to the sub-library (DataService) which looks like:
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="DataService">
      <HintPath>.\External\DataService.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

Question
Since the main app has no direct dependency on Sqlite when I build the app and make the call to the Data Service, I get a runtime error because Sqlite isn't included in my app when it is built.
How do I include Sqlite component in my main app?
Do I just do the : $ dotnet add package SQLite
That would add a direct dependency upon Sqlite.  That seems odd (and wrong).
Why Doesn't Build Process Get Sub-Dependency?
Why doesn't the dotnet build simply discover the dependency that the Data Service has and include the sqlite package since I've added the Data Service dependency to my main app?
Is there something I need to add to get the sub-dependency added to my main app?
Error - From Main App
When I make the call to the sub-library's method (which in turn will write to sqlite) I see the following error in my Main App:

Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=9.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=9.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'


Is DataService a separate project?
Dependencies are typically scoped to .Net projects (and therefore outlined in the .csproj file). If DataService is a project which is imported by MainApp, then only the externally visible (public) members of DataService will be accessible to MainApp. The way to interface with Sqlite from MainApp would be to call a method on DataService that subsequently interacts with Sqlite.
Also providing a copy of the error message would be helpful.

The DataService is a separate project that I'm building.  However, the Main App just references the DataService via DLL (not project reference).  I'll add the error (library ref error ) that I see from the main app.

In that case, the main project has no knowledge of the SQlite library being used. You'll need to deploy it manually in the folder you main app is deployed to. If you want it to be copied automatically when building, you need to package your lib with it's dependency in a nuget package.
